# Xcode 5 Error: Expression result unused

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

So I am coding in Xcode 5 and I am working on a project that allows people to save an image that is displayed on the image view. I typed in this code...

```
[starImageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.jpg"]];
```

And then this error/warning came up...

***"Expression result unused"***

If you have ANY other questions about my project, let me know!

ALL answers are GREATLY appreciated!!!

Thanks!

Eric

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/initWithImage%3a), `initWithImage` is an *instance method*, which returns an UIImaveView object instance.

It does two things:

1: adjusts the reciever's frame (in your case starImageView) to match the size of the specified image

2: Returns another UIImageView initialized with the specified image.

Why you are getting the warning:
You are not assigning the object returned by the method call. You should have something like this to get rid of this warning:

```
id newImageView = [starImageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.jpg"]];
```

(Then you will get a warning unused variable for newImageView, as you are assigning value but not using it anywhere)

Comment: You should not call an init method on anything other than a newly-allocated instance (i.e. the result from `+alloc` or `+allocWithZone:`). And, in the vast majority of cases, the allocation and initialization should be combined into one expression (e.g. `[[SomeClass alloc] init...]`).

Answer (score 1):

If `starImageView` has already been initialised and you are trying to set an image to imageview then you should use following statement instead.

`[starImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.jpg"]];`